# Python "ModuleNotFoundError:", but module does appear to be installed per Command Prompt

Tags: python, openpyxl, modulenotfounderror, mu

I am very new to Python/programming, having recently installed Python 3.10. I have already installed the Openpyxl module, i.e. when I check on CMD I get this:

```
C:\Users\hadam>pip install openpyxl
Requirement already satisfied: openpyxl in c:\users\hadam\appdata\local\programs\python\python310\lib\site-packages (3.0.9)
Requirement already satisfied: et-xmlfile in c:\users\hadam\appdata\roaming\python\python310\site-packages (from openpyxl) (1.1.0)
```

I am trying to run some code which I have just copied from here (i.e. I have just edited the file path names):
https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-how-to-copy-data-from-one-excel-sheet-to-another/

However, when I try to run this script (via the Mu editor), I get the following error message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\users\hadam\appdata\local\programs\python\python310\scripts\test1.py", line 2, in <module>
    import openpyxl as xl;
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'openpyxl'
>>>
```

Can anyone tell me why the Mu editor cannot find Openpyxl, or what I can do to execute this programme?

Thanks

Comment: Fix the settings of your (Mu) editor. The editor/IDE, to be able to run a python code, needs to know where to find the (python) interpreter. It is most probably using a different interpreter than the one you use when you do it yourself on the Prompt. If you are being able to run the code from the prompt (where `openpyxl` is found), once you set Mu settings to use the same/proper interpreter things should work also there.

Comment: are you using python3? Then maybe try  pip3 install openpyxl

Answer (score 1):

Maybe the error is because Openpyxl does not support Python 3.10 build yet. Check the pypi page for supported versions.

Answer (score 0):

Try to open python from the command line, e.g.

```
 C:\users\you> python
```

or

```
C:\users\you> python3
```

or

```
C:\users\you> path\to\python
```

then when python is open

```
>>> import openpyxl as xl
```

If the problem is not present anymore, your Mu editor might be using a different python interpreter/environment: check for its configurations and change it to the one you opened from the terminal.

Answer (score 0):

The simple way to resolve this problem is to install a module in Mu Editor.
Mu Editor provides its own way to install third-party modules.

**How to install third-party modules on Mu editor:
https://codewith.mu/en/tutorials/1.1/pypi**

In addition, this kind of problem usually happens when there is more than one version of pythons.

```
# you can check what version of python will be executed on Prompt by typing:
C:\Users\hadam>python --version
```

On Mu Editor, there is [REPL] button on the top menu. If you click the button, a new terminal will be open at the bottom. Then, the current version of python will be printed on the terminal. (see https://codewith.mu/en/tutorials/1.1/python)

Or, you can type the same command on the Terminal to check a version of python on Mu Editor.

```
In [1]: python --version
```

Now, compare the two versions of python, they might be different from each other. Meaning that the module is installed but for another version of python.